# improve this table with latex

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
{Après-midi}\hspace{1cm}&\hspace{1cm}{Matin} & \hspace{1cm}   \\
\hline
{\small
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
x & y & z
 \\
 \hline
19h25 & 12h56 & 41
\\
\hline
20h32 & 14h00 & 37
\\
\hline
21h43 & 15h13 & 38
\\
\hline
22h48 & 16h23 & 43
\\
\hline
23h51 & 17h20 & 51
\\
\hline
22h48 & 16h23 & 59
\\
\hline
22h48 & 16h23 & 67
\\
\hline
 \end{tabular} }
& {\small
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
x & y & z
 \\
 \hline
6h56 & 0h35 & 45 
\\
\hline
7h56 & 1h33 & 38
\\
\hline
9h08 & 2h42 & 36
\\
\hline
10h19 & 3h54 & 40
\\
\hline
20h32 & 14h00 & 47
\\
\hline
-- & 14h00 & 55
\\
\hline
0h25 & 6h25 & 63
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
& 1
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

i want get 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 beside 41,37,... 
I get only 1 ?

Comment: it isn't clear why you are using nested tabulars but having used two you presumably want a third, one-column tabular where you have 1 that has `\begin{tabular}{c}1\\2\\3\\4..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the comment about nested tabulars, but I've left that part unchanged. Perhaps this is what you want?  If you only need the numbering on last column, then you need to remove the `T` column specification (and all the final `&`s) from the 'Après-midi' column. I've used the `\thead` macro from the very useful `makecell` package to allow line breaks in centred column headings

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{tcount}
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\stepcounter{tcount}\thetcount}c}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{tcount}{0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\thead{Après-midi\\Afternoon}&\thead{Matin\\Morning}    \\
\hline
{\small
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|T}
x & y & z &\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
 \\
 \hline
19h25 & 12h56 & 41 &
\\
\hline
20h32 & 14h00 & 37 &
\\
\hline
21h43 & 15h13 & 38  &
\\
\hline
22h48 & 16h23 & 43 &
\\
\hline
23h51 & 17h20 & 51 &
\\
\hline
22h48 & 16h23 & 59 &
\\
\hline
22h48 & 16h23 & 67 &
 \end{tabular} }
& {\small
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|T}
x & y & z & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
 \\
 \hline
6h56 & 0h35 & 45  &
\\
\hline
7h56 & 1h33 & 38  &
\\
\hline
9h08 & 2h42 & 36 &
\\
\hline
10h19 & 3h54 & 40 &
\\
\hline
20h32 & 14h00 & 47 &
\\
\hline
-- & 14h00 & 55 &
\\
\hline
0h25 & 6h25 & 63 &
\end{tabular}}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]